# How to do multiple join / group by selects using sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database with one table called orig:

```
CREATE TABLE orig (sdate date, stime integer, orbnum integer);
```

What I want to do is select the first date/time for each orbnum. The only problem is that stime holds the time as a very awkward integer.

Assuming a six-digit number, the first two digits show the hour, the 3./4. show the minutes, and the last two digits show the seconds. So a value of 12345 is 1:23:45, whereas a value of 123456 is 12:34:56.

I figured I'd do this using two nested join/group statements, but somehow I cannot get it to work properly. Here's what I've got so far:

```
select s.orbnum, s.sdate, s.stime
from (
    select t.orbnum, t.sdate, t.stime, min(t.sdate) as minsdate
    from (
        select orbnum, sdate, stime, min(stime) as minstime
        from scia group by orbnum, sdate
    ) as t inner join orig as s on s.stime = t.minstime and s.sdate = t.sdate and s.orbnum = t.orbnum
) as d inner join scia as s on s.stime = d.stime and s.sdate = minsdate and s.orbnum = d.orbnum
where s.sdate >= '2002-08-01' limit 0,200;
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: no such column: t.orbnum
```

I'm sure it's just some stupid mistake, but actually, I'm quite new to SQL ...

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

*Edit:*

After fixing the obvious typo, the query runs -- but returns an empty result set. However, the table holds ~10yrs of data, with about 12 orbnums per day and about 4-5 different times per orbnum. So I guess there's some mistake in the logic of the query ...

Answer (score 0):

In your last join, you have `d`, which is the result of your double nested select, and you join `s` on it. From there, `t` is not visible. That’s why you get the “no such column: t.orbnum” error. Maybe you meant `s.orbnum = d.orbnum`?

Comment: thanks, i feel kind of stupid now. but it didn't really help. the query returns an empty result set, even though it shouldn't. see edit.